# Best way to find $SU(2)$ transformation representation in if I know the desired output?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, representation-theory, rotation, linear-algebra

I have two doublets in $SU(2)$: 
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i\\ \end{pmatrix}.$

What is the easiest way to figure out the vector $\vec{\theta} $ in the $SU(2)$ transformation: 
$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i\\ \end{pmatrix} = e^{-\frac{i}{2}\vec{\theta}\cdot \vec{\sigma}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$

(where $\vec{\sigma}$ are the Pauli matrices)

Comment: Do you need the output to be precisely $(1, i)$, or would you be content with output up to a phase factor? e.g. would you be happy with $(e^{-i\pi/4}, e^{i\pi/4})$?